# Trouble Connecting Flask Backend to Kivy App Using UrlRequest

Tags: python, flask, kivy

I’m currently working on a project that involves a Flask backend and a Kivy app. My goal is to establish communication between the two using Kivy’s UrlRequest. However, it appears that my Flask app isn’t receiving the data as expected from the UrlRequest.

Here are the key points:

- I’ve set up the Flask backend to handle requests.
- The Kivy app initiates a UrlRequest to the Flask endpoint.
- Despite correct URL configuration, the Flask app seems to reject the data sent via UrlRequest.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```py
This is my back end endpoint:
@recipes_blueprint.route('/ask_mobile', methods=['POST'])
def ask_recipe_mobile():
    content = request.json['content']
    print(content)
    recipe = recipe_request_mobile(content)
    return jsonify({
        'data': recipe,
        'status': 200,
        'message': 'Recipe created successfully'
    }), 200
```

My Kivy app is :

```
    def load_content(self, query):
        params = urlencode({'content': query})
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        req = UrlRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/recipes/ask_mobile',
                         req_body=params, req_headers=headers, on_error=handle_error)
        print(req.req_body)
```

I get a 400 error on my back end

Answer (score 0):

You send data urlencoded, but expect json on the server side. Because of this, the server throws an error when it tries to parse the data.

The following example shows how to send the data in json format.

```py
import json

# ...

    def load_content(self, query):
        req_headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        req_body=json.dumps({'content': query})
        req = UrlRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/reciepes/ask_mobile', 
            req_headers=req_headers, 
            req_body=req_body, 
            on_success=self.handle_success)

    def handle_success(self, request, result):
        print(result)
```